# PHP While Loop Summing

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am currently making a very standard ecommerce shopping cart, I have set it up so that the items display in the shopping cart looping onto a table from my database.

```
table class="large-16" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <tr>
     <th>Action:</th>
     <th>Product:</th>
     <th>Price:</th>
     <th>Size:</th>
     <th>Color:</th>
     <th>Quantity:</th>
     <th>Price Total:</th>
   </tr>



  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="delete-product-handler.php?id=<?php
          echo $row['product_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this product from your shopping cart?")">
          <img src="img/delete.png" alt="delete button">Remove</a>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['product_price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['product_size']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['product_color']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['product_quantity']; ?></td>
      <td><?php $totalItemPrice[] = ($row['product_price'] * $row['product_quantity']);
            echo $totalItemPrice; ?></td>

    </tr>
```

As you can see it is set up to add up the Price of each item to the amount of the same item I wish to purchase.

How can I now add up the total of all the summed up prices to get an over all price of everything I am purchasing?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your array before while.

```
$totalItemPrice = array();
```

And then you can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
echo array_sum($totalItemPrice);
```

Comment: It now says:  Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array.

Comment: You have to define the $totalItemPrice array before the while loop.

Comment: I did but as I said the Warning: array_sum() is the result.

Comment: Please, edit you answer providing the code you currently use.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, thanks to everyone who assisted.

Here is the coding used:

```
    <?php 
                $total = 0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="delete-product-handler.phpid=>?php ?>" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this product from your shopping cart?")"><img src="img/delete.png" alt="delete button">Remove</a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_price']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_size']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_color']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_quantity']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_price'] * $row['product_quantity'];
                        $total += $row['product_price'] * $row['product_quantity']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php } ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="6"></td>
                        <td>Total: <?php echo $total; ?></td></tr>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> ```
> td><?php $totalItemPrice[] = $row['product_price']*$row['product_quantity']);
> echo $totalItemPrice; ?></td>
> ```

by this

> ```
> <td><?php echo $row['product_price']*$row['product_quantity']; ?></td>
> ```